# Replacing the to_s method in Ruby. Not printing out desired string

Tags: ruby, class

So, I am just beginning to learn Ruby and I included a to_s method in my Class so that I can simply pass the Object to a puts method and have it return more than just the Object ID. I made a mistake and defined it as such:

```
def to_s
    puts "I'm #{@name} with a health of #{@health}."
end
```

instead of:

```
def to_s
    "I'm #{@name} with a health of #{@health}."
end
```

So, when I do this while using the first code block:

```
player1 = Player.new("larry")
puts player1
```

I get an object ID and a string when I execute the above two lines of code and not just the string. Why is this? I get this output:

```
I'm Larry with a health of 90.
#<Player:0x007fca1c08b270>
```

I am trying to think about why the first version of the program doesn't just print out the string to console, but instead returns the object ID and the string. I thought that when I pass the object to puts, all that is happening is that puts turns around and calls the to_s method to get the player's string representation. Right?

Comment: I tried to repeat this problem, but everything was okay. Could you check: `player1.to_s`?

Comment: So when I call player1.to_s, it simply prints out the string which seems correct. When I call puts player1, I get the string AND and object ID like this: #<Player:0x007f92ed08b3d0>. Why is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When given arguments that are not strings or arrays `puts` calls `rb_obj_as_string` to turn its arguments into strings (see [rb_io_puts](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/io.c#L6853))

If you search for rb_obj_as_string through the ruby codebase (I find http://rxr.whitequark.org useful for this) you can see it's [defined](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_2/string.c#L1011) as

```
VALUE rb_obj_as_string(VALUE obj)
{
  VALUE str;

  if (RB_TYPE_P(obj, T_STRING)) {
    return obj;
  }
  str = rb_funcall(obj, id_to_s, 0);
  if (!RB_TYPE_P(str, T_STRING))
    return rb_any_to_s(obj);
  if (OBJ_TAINTED(obj)) OBJ_TAINT(str);
  return str;
}
```

In brief this:

- returns straightaway if the argument is already a string
- calls `to_s`
- if the result is not a string, call `rb_any_to_s` and return that.

`rb_any_to_s` is what implements the default "class name and id" result that you're seeing: for any object it returns a string of the form `#<ClassName: 0x1234567890abcdef>`

Returning to your code, when you run `puts player1` it calls  `rb_obj_as_string` to convert your player to a string.

This first calls your `to_s` method, which uses `puts` to output your message. Your method then returns nil (because that's what `puts` always returns) so ruby calls `rb_any_to_s`, and that is what the outermost `puts` ends up using.

Comment: what does rb_any_to_s do anyway? Does it just force return a string value of the object's ID? Sorry, I am not clear yet on how to read the whitequark docs yet... still trying.

Comment: @Jwan622, **what does rb_any_to_s do anyway?** *is what implements the default "class name and id" result that you're seeing* --> In other words, it returns the string `#<Player:0x007fca1c08b270>`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `puts` returns nil, so does that version of `to_s`:

```
def to_s
  puts "I'm #{@name} with a health of #{@health}."
end
```

With `puts player1`, `player1.to_s` method is called, which prints the String "I'm ...", but the return value is that of the `puts` call inside `to_s`, which is `nil`.

So `player1` is an object of which `to_s` returns nil, thus `puts player1` in the end prints the result of the inherited `to_s` method.

Answer (score 1):

**Experiential Rule:** If the result of to_s is not a String, then ruby returns the default.

**Application of Rule:** puts() returns nil, which means your to_s method returns nil, and nil is not a String, so ruby returns the default.

Another example:

```
class Object
  def inspect
    'obj-inspect'
  end

  def to_s
    'obj-to_s'
  end
end

class Dog 
  def inspect
    'dog-inspect'
  end

  def to_s
    nil
  end
end

puts Dog.new

--output:--
#<Dog:0x1001b6218>
```

Once to_s fails to return a String, ruby does not continue along the method lookup path to call another to_s method.  That makes some sense: the method was found, so there is no need to look up the method in a parent class.  Nor does ruby alternatively call inspect() to get a result.

Where does the default come from?  I think ruby must directly call the Object#to_s method which is a method written in C--thereby bypassing ruby's method overriding mechanism.

Comment: If puts Dog.new is supposed to return nil and doesn't return a String, why does it out the Dog:Object ID?

Comment: @Jwan622, 1) What `puts Dog.new` returns is irrelevant.  2) I explained what I think happens when to_s does not return a String.  See all the text after the code example--and as Frederick Cheung's answer explains that is essentially what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The first example using `puts` will write to stdout and return nil. It does not actually return a String.

The second example returns a String.

If you want to write to the console you can, but you will need to also return the value.

```
#or put it in a variable first and return that after you print it
def to_s
  puts "I'm #{@name} with a health of #{@health}."
  "I'm #{@name} with a health of #{@health}."
end
```

Comment: Assign the string to a variable and use it instead of interpolating the values into the string twice.

Comment: yeah, I put that in the comment as an exercise for the reader.