# to_s is not returning the expected value

Tags: ruby

Consider the following code

```
class Raj
  def to_s
    puts 'abc'
    return 'hello'
  end
end

obj=Raj.new
puts obj
```

output

```
abc
hello # hello is printed because to_s returned the value of 'hello'
```

but look at the code snippet below

```
class Raj
  def to_s
    puts 'abc'
  end
end

obj=Raj.new
puts obj
```

Output

```
abc
<Raj:0x899610> #Object address this time
```

It's printing object address here, but according to the above code it has to print the returned value, so for the second coding snippet, it must be nil because puts would return the value of nil,right?  Why it's not printing? I know nil value can't be printed but it has to print the empty space, but it's printing the object address so it's sure that it's not nil. Why it is so?

Comment: Short answer : to_s should return a String.
If it doesn't, puts uses the object instead.

Comment: @EricDuminil Yes,but If it doesn't return then it's printing Object address, the question is where does the object address is coming from now? Because we have override to_s method already. So how object method is still being printed?

Comment: There's some logic involved (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26376728/6419007)
If to_s doesn't return a String, Object#to_s is used instead :
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-to_s
Even though Raj#to_s overrides Object#to_s, Object#to_s can still be called by puts.

Comment: @EricDuminil
No it's not

`class Object
 def to_s
  puts 'hi'
 end
end



class Raj
 def to_s
 puts 'raja'
 end
 

end

obj=Raj.new

No it's not calling Object to_s method, In the above program I have rewritten the function of to_s in Object class, but it's still printing the address.

Comment: You're right, Kernel#puts doesn't call Object#to_s, it calls the same C function that is used by Object#to_s : rb_any_to_s.
So overriding Object#to_s won't change anything.

Comment: @EricDuminil Okay, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. You can override Kernel#puts :
module Kernel;def puts(*p);print *p,"\n";end;end
Raj#to_s should then behave as expected.

Comment: That's interesting. Thanks.